# Can anyone tell how SMS Api Extension (v1.3) working in civicrm?

Tags: civisms

Can anyone tell how [SMS Api Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sms-api) (v1.3) working in civicrm ?

Comment: pls add some more information to your question and explain what you have already discovered or tried

Answer (score 2):

You can try the SMS API with the API explorer. Basically all it does is enable the sending of an SMS (which is in CiviCRM) using an API. But it is hard to answer such a generic question.